# Sci-fi novel about a planet with a semi-intelligent tree-like species, and a golden insect-like species

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I am trying to track down a sci-fi novel that I read many years ago.  The story is about a world recently colonised by humans, but which has its own indigenous life forms.  These comprise a semi-intelligent tree-like species, and a golden insect-like species who the humans discover are the source of a mineral which they value and harvest.  The protagonist in the story discovers that the insects have a hive mind intelligence and the story is basically about the interaction of the protagonist with the insects and his fellow humans.

I realise that this is a fairly sketchy outline to base a search on, and my attempts at googling on this basis are the evidence of this, but I’m hoping that this may ring a bell with someone on the forum.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be the War for Eternity / Fenerille series by Christopher Rowley?  That had semi-sentient trees, hive insects that produce a drug that extends human life.  I don't think the hives were intelligent and there was another bear like alien species (Fein).  There were 4 books in the series published between 1983 and 1993

Answer (score 3):

Could it be *[Semiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiosis_(novel))* by Sue Burke? I didn't read it myself but I took your question as a challenge for searching the web.

**Edit** After having posted the answer I noticed you said having read it "many years ago"; thus the answer wouldn't fit.

Comment: I have read (and enjoyed) Semiosis, but it has no mention of golden insects.

Comment: How sure are you of the details? This sounds a lot like Richard McKenna's 'Hunter, Come Home'. Positives: It has a semi-intelligent trees, little thingeys that fly through the air, newly-arrived humans and a man who begins to comprehend the forest. Negatives: The humans plan to wipe out the forest and establish a game preserve.

Comment: Very sure about the insects, and the trees.  Just read a synopsis of Hunter Come Home, thank you for your feedback but this is not what I am after, however I’m realising side-benefit of this discussion... new books to read, new authors

Comment: I've only read a few of McKenna's SF stories, but 'The Sand Pebble's' is a great book.